# how to catch click on page body

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a number of divs in it and when someone clicks one of them it calls a javascript method.  I need to be able to also trigger another method call if someone clicks the body, meaning they didn't click a div but outside the div.  When I put a jquery click handler on the body tag it fires even when you click the div.  Anyone know how I can restrict the click to anything outside the divs?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine somwhere in the click event will be a reference to the element which 'was underneath' at the time, often this is the 'target' if you can get a handle on that it should be pretty simple to perform a conditional check to find out if it was a div, or the html body element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I was able to use the jquery target id to see if it's the body.  That worked great.

Comment: selector: `body :not(*)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the original target of the click event. It is accessible as `e.target` where `e` is the click event.

```
var div = document.getElementById('the-div');

document.body.onclick = function (e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while (target !== document.body) {
    if (target === div) {
      // The user clicked inside the div
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }

  // do the stuff you want when they click outside the div here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `onclick` callback on the whole document:

```
document.onclick = function(){
    alert("CLICK");
};
```

See also [JavaScript event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)

Answer (score -1):

You could make the entire window track click events, where the div, if clicked, will stop event propagation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style>

            #wrapper {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }

            #antidiv {
                position:absolute;
                left:40px;
                top:80px;

                width:100px;
                height:100px;

                background-color:#3FF;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="antidiv"></div>


        </div>

        <script>

            document.getElementById("antidiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }, false);

            document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                alert("You didn't click the div!");
            }, false);




        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the full HTML? Use JSFiddle for that.

Comment: Why not? :) I'll look in to JSFiddle for future responses though.

Comment: Well, the actual code related to the question is below the fold.